# JQuery Mobile file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I've been looking everywhere and cannot find any examples on it.

Does anyone know where I could find anything on uploading files using JQuery Mobile please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery doesn't in and of itself offer assistance for file upload. What does however is a jQuery plugin called [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/). Its implementation and use shouldn't be any different between standard jQuery and jQuery Mobile.

Comment: can it be used along with jquery mobile, I am asking this because there should be any compatible  issues. Also iOS doesnt allow browsers to access the file system.

Comment: I say this having little experience developing anything for iOS, but those jQuery guys are ALL ABOUT cross-platform compatibility. I'm sure you'll be fine.

Comment: Just to know if I can save some tests... does anyone tested Uploadify on iOS devices?