# Add File Upload Control in asp.net mobile website?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Currently, I'm working on asp.net mobile website and I've to implement one functionality related to upload file in mobile website.

I'm using asp:upload Control but, It's not working in mobile website.

I have been searching in google for this issue since last week, But I can't find any relative source or blog.

Can anyone help me on this topic?

Comment: check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947785/jquery-mobile-file-upload

Comment: It's give me error!!! I think It's not supported jquery.

Answer (score 1):

In view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

In Control:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            // Verify that the user selected a file
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                // extract only the fielname
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
            // redirect back to the index action to show the form once again

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

and remove the jquerymobile script from your page. Like in MVC4

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery", "~/bundles/jquerymobile")
```

Remove this line, it's the source of the conflict.