# jQuery Mobile can upload file?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, upload

I'm finding a jQuery Mobile plugin to upload image from my android tablet onto server, but so hopelessly! I've found [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947785/jquery-mobile-file-upload) but `Flash uploader` on smartphone (or table) seems that a bad solution.

May jQuery Mobile support upload file from browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery Mobile doesn't do anything to disable file uploads.  It just doesn't style them due to browser security restrictions and you can't upload files with the AJAX navigation system.  I use file uploads with jQuery Mobile in my application with no problem at all.

If you want to use file uploads with jQuery Mobile you have to do two things:

1)  Turn off Ajax navigation using data-ajax="false" on your form definition because you can't upload files using Ajax.

2)  Specify the appropriate encoding type of enctype="multipart/form-data" on your form.

Comment: Now if JQM would style the file upload to match the rest of the UI, that would be nice...